# hashmap with many to many relationship hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hashmap, many-to-many

I have a situation where I need many to many relationship with extra column and the collection is a HashMap.

Entities Device and UDA are having a many to many relationship with an additional column "value"

Hence I defined another Entity DeviceUDA and thus broke the many to many relation into two one to many relations

But within the Device class, I need a HashMap of (UDA, value)

I attempted the following design.

My classes are as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Device {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int ID; 
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device")  
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")
    Map<DeviceUDA,UDAValue> udaMap;
}

@Entity
public class UDA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int ID; 
    String name;
    String descr;
}

@Entity
public class DeviceUDA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int ID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DEVICEID", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    Device device;

    @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="UDAID", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    UDA uda;

    @Embedded
    UDAValue value;
}

@Embeddable
public class UDAValue {
    String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

This does not seem to be correct design.
The problem seems to be at the use of embeddedable class UDAValue in Device class's hashMap (as its value)
Gives exception: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: Aricent.DeviceInventory.model.Device.set[Aricent.DeviceInventory.model.UDAValue]

Please suggest me how I can correctly design what I intend.Thanks.

Comment: One correction. In Device Class, I actually need a Map<UDA, UDAValue>

Comment: In fact, I could successfully get a Map<UDA, DeviceUDA> and from DeviceUDA, I would get the embedded value. But it looks more intuitive as an API if it was Map<UDA, UDAValue>. So the problem now only boils down to how to use an embedded class in the hashmap (Value)